# Нахождение суммы цифр числа

Tags: java, математика, числа

Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти сумму цифр числа, не используя конвертацию в String.

```
    public class SumOfDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int d = 1776;// число взято от фонаря, в задаче надо считать некоторое количество чисел из файла, но это выходит за рамки моего вопроса, число может быть любого размера
        int e = 0;
        while (d > 0){
            e = e + (d % 10);
            d = (d - e) / 10;
        }

        System.out.print(e);

    }
}
```

Этот код почему-то выдает результат на 2 меньше ожидаемого. Я сначала думал, что не выполняется первая итерация цикла, но, попробовав поставить другое число, получил ожидаемый результат -2. В чем я напортачил?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тело цикла:

```
e += d % 10;
d /= 10;
```

Comment: Ясно. при делении инт отрезает дробную часть. Что в моем коде произошло. Я уже сижу час думаю, что не так. Я просто хочу понять, как работает, чтобы в дальнейшем такой ошибки не делать.

Answer (score 0):

У меня другой вариант. Решение для трехзначного числа. 
Для любого числа считайте циклом. 
Общая идея такая: переводите число в string и из него в массив char символов. Затем каждый символ снова переводите в Integer. Считаете сумму

```
String s =  Integer.toString(number);
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
int i1 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[0]);
int i2 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[1]);
int i3 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[2]);
int sum = i1+i2+i3;
return sum;
```